# Spring boot application does not start when ActiveMQ failover transport fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want my Spring Boot application to start regardless if it can connect to JMS or not. I have this minimal example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class JmsActivemqFailoverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JmsActivemqFailoverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class JmsReceiver {
        @JmsListener(destination = "inbox")
        public void receive(Message message) {
            System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
        }
    }

    @RestController
    public static class HelloWorldController {
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String helloWorld() {
            return "Hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

when `application.properties` contains:

`spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://non-existing-broker:61616`

I can get response from `helloWorld` endpoint. When I change property to:

`spring.activemq.broker-url=failover:(tcp://non-existing-broker:61616)`

Application keeps trying to connect to broker and I can not get response from my REST endpoint.

Please advice, how can I have application running without waiting for ActiveMQ Failover transport to succeed.

Example code available at https://github.com/madoxas/jms-activemq-failover

Comment: i just tried your code.  application starts and rest endpoint is reachable,

Comment: @pvpkiran could you please try again. In logs I get a warning: `Failed to connect to [tcp://non-existing-broker:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.` Executing `curl http://localhost:8080/` I get `Connection refused`.

Comment: @pvpkiran it looks like you are not using failover transport. Please make sure that you have `failover:(...` before the broker url. I want it to work with failover transport as it works without it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is:

1. Disable automatic JMS container startup with property `spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=false`
2. Start JMS container after application has started:

   ```
   @Component
   public class JmsStarter implements ApplicationRunner {
       private final JmsListenerEndpointRegistry jmsRegistry;

       public JmsStarter(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry jmsRegistry) {
           this.jmsRegistry = jmsRegistry;
       }

       @Override
       public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
           for (MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer : jmsRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
               listenerContainer.start();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Ya. You were right. I missed `failover`, I was about to suggest the same solution. for datasources, there is a property in springboot like `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true`. But there is no such thing for jms. You can create a bug in springboot